# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named utils

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the python code in jupyter.

The error I'm getting is:

`from utils import get_data ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

Which relates to line:

```
from utils import get_data
```

I even installed this package but it still tells utils module not found

> `conda install -c conda-forge python-utils.`

Comment: Maybe you installed it in a virtual environment, conda or virenv

Comment: @theX I have checked using promt but it says package already installed is it the correct way of checking?

Comment: In your home (main) environment? You could still be in your virtual environment. EDIT: wait. **Jupyter notebook?** I think we're missing the Jupyter part.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few reasons why you get such an error common one are

1. naming a variable, function as utils
2. naming your file name as utils (probably this 2)
3. It wasn't downloaded correctly